# Electrode doesn't show dynamic data in page source

Tags: reactjs, walmart-electrode

Using electrode, I noticed this weird behaviour -

When I view the page source after the page fully loads with all the api calls and data, I am only able to view the content that is static for example, the hyper links, headings, footer links etc.

I have created a custom token handler which checks the `context` object and populates the custom tokens present in the `index.html`. 
So, whenever, I `console.log(context.user.content)`, only the data that is static such as hyperlinks, headings, footer links are logged.

I guess this is the problem but I am not able to wrap my head around as to why electrode doesn't recognise the content being rendered dynamically.

Token-Handler.js file

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

const emptyTitleRegex = /<title[^>]*><\/title>/;

module.exports = function setup(options) {
  // console.log({ options });
  return {
    INITIALIZE: context => {
      context.user.helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    },
    PAGE_TITLE: context => {
      const helmet = context.user.helmet;
      const helmetTitleScript = helmet.title.toString();
      const helmetTitleEmpty = helmetTitleScript.match(emptyTitleRegex);

      return helmetTitleEmpty ? `<title>${options.routeOptions.pageTitle}</title>` : helmetTitleScript;
    },
    REACT_HELMET_SCRIPTS: context => {
      const scriptsFromHelmet = ["link", "style", "script", "noscript"]
        .map(tagName => context.user.helmet[tagName].toString())
        .join("");
      return `<!--scripts from helmet-->${scriptsFromHelmet}`;
    },
    META_TAGS: context => {
      console.log(context,'123') //this is where I am checking
      return context.user.helmet.meta.toString();
    }
  };
};
```

default.js

```
module.exports = {
  port: portFromEnv() || "3000",
  webapp: {
    module: "electrode-react-webapp/lib/express",
    options: {
      prodBundleBase: '/buy-used-car/js/',
      insertTokenIds: false,
      htmlFile: "./{{env.APP_SRC_DIR}}/client/index.html",
      paths: {
        "*": {
          content: {
            module: "./{{env.APP_SRC_DIR}}/server/views/index-view"
          },
        }
      },
      serverSideRendering: true,
      tokenHandler: "./{{env.APP_SRC_DIR}}/server/token-handler"
    }
  }
};
```

Any clue anyone?

**EDIT 1**

However, any following updates that occur on the meta tags are rendered. I'm not sure that is something electrode allows or is a feature of `react-helmet`.

**EDIT 2**

SSR is enabled in electrode.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the docs, realised that there was a slight misunderstanding. So, if data needs to be present in the page source, it needs to be pre-rendered by the server.

Why it wasn't showing at the time I asked the question? Because, data was being evaluated at run-time due ot which the page source only rendered the static content.

Electrode already provides an abstraction, each component that is being rendered has an option to load with pre-fetched data. The catch here is, you have to evaluate what all data needs to be present at runtime because **more data is directly proportional to page loading time** (as the server won't resolve unless the api you are depending on returns you with either a success or failure )

In terms of implementation, each route has a parameter called `init-top` which is executed before your page loads.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: withRouter(Root),
    init: "./init-top",
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: Home,
        init: "./init-home"
      },
```

in `init-home`, you can define it something on the lines of -

```js
import reducer from "../../client/reducers";
const initNumber = async () => {
  const value = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(123), 2000));
  return { value };
};
export default async function initTop() {
  return {
    reducer,
    initialState: {
      checkBox: { checked: false },
      number: await initNumber(),
      username: { value: "" },
      textarea: { value: "" },
      selectedOption: { value: "0-13" }
    }
  };
}
```

So,now whenever you load the component, it is loaded with this `initialState` returned in `init-home`

I'll just post it here, in case anyone is stuck.